# change between 'and' and 'or' filter in linq-to-xml in c#

Tags: c#, filter, linq-to-xml

Is it possible to set the filter constraints to 'OR' in linq-to-xml? I iterate through an array in order to filter desired values like this:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(fileName);
IEnumerable<XElement> selectedElements = root.Elements("OrderNum").Elements("Job");

for (int i = 1; i < chkBx.Count(); i++)
{
    if (chkBx[i].Checked == true)
    {
        string element = "Diameter";
        string match = chkBx[i].Text;
        selectedElements = selectedElements.Where(el => (string)el.Parent.Element(element) == match);
    }
}
```

Now the filter will kinda be linked together with an 'AND' statement. What if i want to select an element that statisfy any of these filter conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var filters = chkBx.Where(r => r.Checked).Select(r => r.Text).ToList();
selectedElements = selectedElements.Where(r =>
      filters.Contains((string)r.Parent.Element(element)))
```

Comment: That's horribly expensive as the lazy nature of LINQ-to-Objects will re-evaulate `filters` once of each item in `selectedElements`. At the very least, append `.ToList()` to not make the cost quadratic.

Comment: Very nice and compact to. We could also steal Marc's idea and use a HashSet as that will greatly improve the `Contains` performance. The `.ToList()` then becomes redundant. And you can write it like this `var filters = new HashSet<string>(from r in chkBx where r.Checked select r.Text);`

Comment: Thanks all for quick responses!! I used this one:                   var filters = new HashSet<string>(from r in chkBx where r.Checked select r.Text);
selectedElements = selectedElements.Where(r => filters.Contains((string)r.Parent.Element("Diameter")));

Answer (score 2):

You have three options, depending on the scenario:

- you could `.Union` the queries each time (which could make for a lot of overhead, I suspect)
- you could build a custom expression (lots of work, and not really a good fit for LINQ to Objects)
- you could build a `HashSet<string>` of the matches (my preferred option)

i.e.

```
HashSet<string> matches = new HashSet<string>();

// this next bit can probably be simplified, perhaps using LINQ;
// left alone as it is orthogonal
for (int i = 1; i < chkBx.Count(); i++)   
 {
        if (chkBx[i].Checked == true)
        {
            string element = "Diameter";
            matches .Add(chkBx[i].Text);
        }
    }

var selectedElements = selectedElements.Where(el =>
      matches.Contains((string)el.Parent.Element(element)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways, one way is to build the expression using expression trees (necessary for IQueryable situations). But since you're querying an in-memory model you can maintain a list of predicates and use the `Any` extension to do the filtering.

```
var predicates = new List<Func<XElement, bool>>();

for (int i = 1; i < chkBx.Count(); i++)
{
    if (chkBx[i].Checked)
    {
        var match = chkBx[i].Text;
        predicates.Add(el => (string)el.Parent.Element("Diameter") == match)
    }
}

selectedElements = selectedElements.Where(el => predicates.Any(p => p(el)));
```